# If back-ground colour changes, update database

Tags: html, sql, database, asp-classic

I am working with a colour palette where a user is presented with several colours.

When a user clicks on a specific colour they have the option to change it in a new child window and when they do the new colour is passed through to the parent form-

**Child Window**

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
alert(clicked_id);
window.opener.document.getElementById("quack").innerHTML = clicked_id;
window.opener.document.getElementById("quack").style.background = clicked_id;
window.close ();
}
```

**Parent Window**

```
<tr>
<td id="quack" onclick="myFunction()" style="background-color:<%=(rs("Name") )%>"><%=(rs("Name") )%> </td>

</tr>
```

How in `ASP` if the backgound-colour changes of this specifc box can I send the new value to the database to update it?

So if `background-color` changes where `id = quack` execute SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This is no different that any other type of page. Information can be sent back to the server using GET, POST or an AJAX call.